# Using one remote object and multiple destinations

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, blazeds

In my Flex app, I use one remote object and multiple destinations. Is that a bad idea? It seems to be working just fine except for the one or two fringe cases:

1. It's bad design, but we use the same method name on two different destinations and they seem to conflict when they're called at the same time.
2. Logging errors show a method assigned to one destination as being associated with another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've guessed. This is bad design for a multitude of reasons:

- **Confusing** - you may understand your convention of one object/two destinations but this will present problems should anyone else attempt to contribute or maintain your work.
- **Logging/Debugging Issues** - Should a problem arise down the road, having the logger reporting incorrect information could seriously overcomplicate bug tracking
- **Unnecessary** - I am not familar with your code but in my experience with Remote Objects it is trivial to use a few different ones

My suggestion would be to wrap two remote objects into a single parent object. You can pass this single object/class around and still have access to both destinations.

OR

If you're anticipating adding multiple features, create a singleton class with methods for handling remoting logic. This will keep Remoting access consistent across your application and leaves the destination logic contained in one place.

Comment: My original thinking was that the service endpoint is going to be the same so I can just put a default destination in when the app loads and switch it when I need to. With each new feature we add, we're usually adding a new destination. You're saying that I should define a separate remote object for each destination?

Comment: In this case may I suggest adding a singleton class with static methods to perform your remoting calls. You can leave all the logic for connecting to different destinations in there and have access to the service methods from anywhere in the application.